# Deleting rows in Azure Table Storage Table using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

I want to delete rows from Azure Table Storage Table using the 'RowKey' via Azure Data Factory.  Please can you guide me how I can do this?

Regards,
Rish

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly delete all rows which's RowKey equals 'xxxx'.

If you want to delete entities in azure table storage, you need to provide RowKey and PartitionKey. In ADF, you need to use Lookup activity to get all entities which's RowKey equals 'xxxx'. Then get authorization with web activity. Finally, loop Lookup activity's output by For Each activity in which calls the [Delete Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-entity1) request with RowKey, PartitionKey and authorization using web activity.

Or you can create the Http trigger in Azure Function and delete entities by using SDK. Finally, invoke Http trigger in ADF.

Comment: This is indeed a way to do this, but (and I can't emphasize this enough) WATCH OUT FOR THE COSTS! Looping through every single row in a table storage through ADF is absurdly costly. you are better out using Azure Functions with the Table Storage SDK.